# CSS :first-of-type Pseudo Class not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply a font color to just the first  link in an li component.

The li component has the class "open" when it is clicked.

To achieve this, I have tried using the li a:first-of-type and also li a:first-child psuedo classes, but unfortunately, the color gets applied to all children in the li like so:

[image]

How do I use CSS to only color the first child?: in this case "Section 2"

```css
li.open a:first-of-type {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Section 1</a>
    <ul class="off-canvas__nav-sub">
      <li><a href="#">Sub page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="open">
    <a href="#">Section 2</a>
    <ul class="off-canvas__nav-sub">
      <li><a href="#">Sub page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Section 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Section 4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Section 5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) means the first element of its type among a group of *siblings*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `a` element in your document is the first `a` element of its parent element.

If you want to target the `a` element that is a child of the `li` with `class="open"` then use a child combinator.

```css
li.open > a {}
```